# How Android localization works

Tags: android, localization, android-source

I would like to know, how Android localisation works in Inner code(**AOSP** code level. Under which layer it will come)

Ex: we will have lot of string files in the res folder (like values, values-en,values-au)
Depends on the phone language android will automatically take the corresponding string folder. 
I like to know how Android detect that? Where they written that code in the AOSP.

I  had look on the AOSP code, But unfortunately i didn't get the code. Can anyone  can share the correct code link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

java classes

1. android.content.res.Resources
2. android.content.res.ResourcesImpl
3. android.content.res.AssetManager

native

4. frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/AssetManager.cpp

When you load an res, Resources will forward the config(including locales) + res id to native AssetManager. Native AssetManager will lookup the restable to choose the right res.

Comment: Hi @Yong Thanks a lot  for the input. It's really helps. Is there any developer document that explain these process?. It's hard to get it as beginner.

Comment: It's hard to find an document that explain these process. But you may find this link is helpful. https://developer.sony.com/posts/sony-contributes-runtime-resource-overlay-framework-to-android-code-example/